# I would like to fix a problem with post pagination: i can only see the url title (prev - next) but title is truncated

Tags: pagination

This is my "problem": I can't see a proper pagination in the single post. The url-title corresponding to 'previous article' and 'next article' is truncated, it is broken and it is really awful to see, as in this example:

https://www.sportincasa.it/esercizio-fisico-salute/

In the bottom of the page there are the corresponding titles to prev and next posts. And the are not full text but a part of the title.

Can you help me please? I've tried with CSS setting major height but it still remains the same. So maybe the issue is another one, but I can't find it.

This is the code I have found in the index.php

```
<?php } ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'post-format/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php if ( $nt_antidote_blog_content_type!= 'masonry' || $nt_antidote_blog_content_type=='' ) : ?>
        <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text'          => esc_html__( 'Articoli precedenti', 'nt-antidote' ),
                'next_text'          => esc_html__( 'Prossimi articoli ', 'nt-antidote' ),
                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text"></span>',
            ) ); ?>
```

Thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: The title is being truncated before it's written to the page, so CSS won't help. At first glance I can't see anything built-in that would do this: what is your theme using to generate these - posts_nav_link, next_post_link, or something else? Do you have a the_title filter somewhere that would truncate the name?

Comment: This i the code I found in the index.php     <?php } ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'post-format/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?> <?php if ( $nt_antidote_blog_content_type!= 'masonry' || $nt_antidote_blog_content_type=='' ) : ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination( array( 'prev_text'      => esc_html__( 'Articoli precedenti', 'nt-antidote' ), 'next_text'          => esc_html__( 'Prossimi articoli ', 'nt-antidote' ), 'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text"></span>', ) ); ?>